# SQL last day in moth select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following table which is basically the summary of daily transactions and is loaded nightly.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ DateCreated + Sale  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 20100101    + 1000  +
+ 20100131    + 2000  +
+ 20100210    + 2000  +
+ 20100331    + 4000  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I need to display the sale by month, but only for the last day in each month.

eg

```
JAN    2000
FEB       0
MAR    4000
```

I could probably accomplish this with CASE in my select, but is this efficient? This is SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a calendar table, just added a "IsLastDayOfMonth" column, set the last day of each month. Then joined that to my query, filtering by "IsLastDayOfMonth" only and that worked.

```
select a.datecreated,a.sale
         from salesummary a
 inner join calendar c
on a.datecreated = c.fulldatekey
 and c.IsLastDayOfMonth = 1
group by a.datecreated,a.sale
```

Answer (score 7):

My Q&D solution to this has been to construct a date that's the first day of the next month, then subtract a day.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, but it will not show 0 for missing data:

```
select YEAR(DateCreated) as Year, MONTH(DateCreated) as Month, Sale
from MyTable
where DAY(DateCreated + 1) = 1
```